# Set $_HANDLER environment variable AWS Lambda in Dockerfile or via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, terraform, dockerfile

[image: Image Configuration]

I'm looking to add CMD override for an AWS Lambda via either terraform or docker. The lambda has type image since it is being run from a container. Trying to add the handler through terraform gives

```
Message_: "Please don't provide Handler or Runtime or Layer when the intended function PackageType is Image.",
```

Is there a way to set the _HANDLER to something and be used within the Dockerfile.
CMD "${_HANDLER}"

Ie. $_HANDLER = $LAMBDA_HANDLER
CMD ${_HANDLER} will then point to the lambda handler?

Answer (score 1):

The [`image_config` block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#image_config) allows you to override the command and entrypoint of the container. For example:

```
image_config {
  command = ["app.other_handler"]
}
```